# Laravel Voyager doesn't display uploaded images uploaded to server

Tags: php, laravel, localhost, hosting, voyager

[Laravel Voyager doesn't display images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRa8H.png)

So in local machine everything works well, however recently i moved to hosting and i was confused that voyager doesn't display images.
But Images which i added in local machine is displayed

Comment: Were the images retrieved by  the Browser?  Did you look at the Network tab in your Browser's development tools?   Were the images retrieved with an HTTP status code of "200"? My guess is the images are not stored where Voyager was told they are.  You can also check your app by having https://www.webpagetest.org/ check every request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it, what was the problem.
So, i have used src like storage/***/ and i remembered about other way to write src as {{ asset('storage/' . $yourvariables-> table_name) }}
and it fixed my problem